# GIT fetch remote: SSH timed out on port 22 (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, git

I've got an Oracle VM VirtualBox running Ubuntu 9.10, and also a pysical DELL server running Ubuntu 9.10

I can use putty to connect to both the VM and the DELL. From either I can ssh into the other, albeit using an IP address.

```
ssh user@192.168.1.X
```

Then on both machines, I've got a git repo set up: VM as a clone of DELL - I managed to successfully use *git clone user@192.168.1.X:/path/to/repo/on/DELL*

So VM has DELL as a remote repo called **origin**, and DELL has VM as a remote repo called **siteVM**

I've made some changes in the VM, and commited them.

But if I try to do a fetch from the DELL repo, I get the following:

```
git fetch siteVM
ssh: connect to host 192.169.1.X port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So I'm lost. SSH is working fine, and I cloned the DELL repo onto the VM without any problems at all.

What's stopping SSH working via *git fetch*?

UPDATE: Completely and utterly my own stupid fault. I've put the IP in wrong in my *git remote add* command - I've put 169 instead of 168.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`192.168.1.X` != `192.169.1.X`.

Comment: Oh damn. Please let this day be forgotten :( Thanks

Comment: Ha ha, I found this question because I made that exact mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you could also get this error if the remote machine is no longer available. In the case that it wasn't a  machine you set up on your own...
OR
if the machine has a firewall of some kind blocking your ip or range...